# Jmeter, I have to Run 1000 Concurrent Users data with Auth Token But Before the auth Token is passed to next API the api gets failed

Tags: testing, concurrency, jmeter, load, listener

I am Testing a web application with jmeter for 100 concurrent users when i run for 10 users the api are all passing and auth token is being passed to next api[for 10 users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub0fV.jpg)

but when i try for 50 users the first two api are failing because auth token value is showing as null [50 users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIVAW.jpg) can you guys please help me i have tried all the listeners timers and all possible ways

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshots don't tell the full story, most probably under the load your application fails to return the token.

Try saving response data for the request which returns the token and see how does response look like, it can be done in 2 ways:

- If you're running your test in [non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) - set `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format` property to `xml` and `jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data` to `true`, this way the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) will contain the response data for all the requests
- Use a Listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) configured to save response data into a file:

  [image]

More information:

- [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter)

Comment: Like I can able to see the response auth token using extractor sometimes its unable to store the value and pass it to net request. i assume the problem is not with application with jmeter.

Comment: If you're able to see the token in the response and not seeing it in the next request than yes, it might be a JMeter problem. 1. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries. 2. You might also want to [increase logging level to debug](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the PostProcessor(s) you're using. 3. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html). 4. Make sure that JMeter has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, etc.